# Cannot boot to bootcamp Windows10 without usb

Tags: boot, grub, macbook, microsoft-windows

I have a Macbook pro early 2015 with bootcamp Windows 10. I have installed elementary os to usb flash drive and it boots up via bootcamp windows disk option via GNU Grub. However, now, Windows does not boot without usb showing GNU Grub Version 2.02. I know that I can boot writing some commands there but is there any way of booting automatically?

Thanks!

Comment: What does alt(option)+power button boot list show?